# The maximum size of Data that can be stored in Application scope, Session Scope, Page Scope?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a assignment to switch data stored from application scope to database so I was thinking how much data can be saved maximum in variables when it comes to scopes.

Comment: have you tried to test it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be "it depends". It depends on the amount of available memory you have, it can depend on the application server (unless there's a standardized limit which I doubt), and who knows what else.

But luckily it doesn't matter. You don't need to know how much data you can save in a session for example, because you want to keep the amount to a minimum.

Also, if you're really talking about application scope, then this is even less important, since application scope doesn't usually contain very large amounts of data.